# Can't use django-compress with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django 1.9.6 site deployed to Heroku.  When `DEBUG=False` I was getting a server error (500).  The logs contained no useful information, so I tried running it with `DEBUG=True`.  Now it works fine.  I *think* the issue may be tied to my scss file processing, which really confuses me and I was struggling with.  I recently--among other things--added `COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True` to my settings files, and commenting that out seems to alleviate the problem (although then my scss files don't work).

Some of my static `settings.py`.  Let me know if you need more--so much of this is a mystery to me.  I was trying to follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) as best as I could.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        # other finders..
        'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    )

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

EDIT:

I've gotten logging to work, and I've confirmed that it's a compress error.  I'm getting the error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /

OfflineGenerationError at /
You have offline compression enabled but key "171c3b7763dbc51a465d996f7d920cf5" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

which is the same thing I've gotten locally, except running the suggested command solved it.  Running `heroku run python manage.py compress` doesn't have an effect (no errors running it, though)

Comment: How are you serving your static files? On Heroku or another service?

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to that--I'm so confused by static files in general.  I likely set it up wrong.  I don't know why all of them except my scss files were showing up.  I mostly tried to follow this.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets Will update my question.

Comment: logs contain no useful information but do you mind sharing the logs anyway?

Comment: Does your site run locally with DEBUG=False?

Comment: @DanielHepper At this point, partially.  Some (not all) of the static assets are missing.  I haven't found what's in common with the missing ones yet (all images, but some of the images are loading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest generated by compress was stored in my .gitignore and therefore the one on production was stale.  Adding it to the git repository fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

First off set value for `ALLOW_HOSTS`, this can't be blank when debug is off.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.com', '.2nddomain.com']
```

Because you use compress plugins:
SET

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True

# this where the collectstatic and compress result output
# point your static alias to here 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# in your production env: activate ur virtual environment then run the compress statics command
python manage.py compress
python manage.py collectstatic
```

When Debug is off all exceptions is suppressed for security reason, set admin email in the setting file to let django email all un-caught exception

```
SERVER_EMAIL = 'ur@from-email-address.com'
ADMINS = (
    ('Exceptions Email', 'destination@email.com'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `settings.py` inside the `loggers` section and it should give you more information (this is what helped point me into solving the same problem).

```
"django.request": {
  "handlers": ["console"],
  "level": "ERROR",
  "propagate": True
}
```

For what it's worth, here are my similar `settings.py` settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = "http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/" % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = os.getenv("DJANGO_STATIC_HOST", "") + "/static/"
if DEBUG:
  STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Note: I have no `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATICFILES_FINDERS` and I'm also using `Whitenoise` with `CloudFront` for my static file handling

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried to share a website with 'PythonAnywhere'. I have encountered the same problem and have fixed the problem with 'Allowed_Host'.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

settings.py

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident in my allowed_hosts (also, you should be more specific than `*` for security's sake)

Comment: I made it to get rid of the bad server error. I know it's not safe, but I'm doing it during the project development state and just for testing. Do not blame if I misunderstand your problem. I thought I had a problem with the same problem, so I gave my own solution. Also not good in english :/

Comment: I appreciate it!  It was a good thought and maybe will help others!